# Django 1.5 + Postgres Database Records Disappearing

Tags: django, database, postgresql, orm

We have a system that allows people to place orders which contain one or more products. Out of 1500 transactions per week for the last month, I have had two orders which are simply no longer in the database.

My logging indicates that we got past the creation of the product ORM object, plus a subsequent modification and a call to save(), and also the creation of an order ORM object, which subsequent modifications and a call to save().

After this happens, it looks from the log like we successfully contact our payment processor and everything comes back, but the database contains no trace of the records having been created.

My questions are:

1. Does Django's ORM buffer created objects somehow? Maybe processing is dying completely at some point (without logging any exceptions), and the objects don't really exist yet in the database.
2. I am the only person with access to the admin site, and I certainly have not gone in and deleted specific records. I have also not implemented the ability to delete Orders or Products, because I want them in the database forever. Is there any other way that objects may be deleted after being successfully created that I do not know about?
3. I read that checking the pk member for None is the canonical way of determining whether an object has been written to the database. In my reproduction cases, this check passes.

EDIT:

e4c5's excellent answer gave me awareness of Django's database transaction behavior options. Two additional environmental factors lead to this behavior, and my inability to diagnose it:

1. We had enabled Django's TransactionMiddleware, which rolls back all database operations if a view does not return successfully.
2. A logging configuration issue was showing uncaught exception stack traces in this particular module when running in the debugging server, but not when running in our production environment (nginx/supervisor/gunicorn).

An uncaught exception was being raised after the create() and save() methods were called, which caused the TransactionMiddleware to roll back the database entries. The logging issue was suppressing the uncaught exception trace from being logged, so I had no idea what was happening.

For this specific view, I enabled Django's default transaction behavior with:

```
with transaction.autocommit():
    ...do my stuff...
```

Read about Django's transaction options here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests

Comment: Maybe your application forgot to commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Does Django's ORM buffer created objects somehow?

There isn't any buffering as such. When you say save, the object is [saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#why-django-uses-autocommit) unless you  have changed the auto commit behaviour.

> Django’s default behavior is to run with an open transaction which it
>   commits automatically when any built-in, data-altering model function
>   is called. For example, if you call model.save() or model.delete(),
>   the change will be committed immediately

(the above is from the 1.5 documentation)

2) Is there any other way that objects may be deleted after being successfully created that I do not know about?

Objects can be deleted directly in the database using the database client.

3) pk == None check

If the object has not been saved, pk is None and gets a positive integer value after save (assume your primary key is an auto field). There is one caveat, if you have changed the auto commit behaviour and you are managing transactions manually, the object may aquire a not null pk but it may not exist in the database until the commit is made.

Only the current transaction can see this non null primary key until the transaction is committed. If it is rolled back the object would cease to exist.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it lead me directly to the problem. See my edit for environmental details which lead to this misunderstanding.

Comment: Glad to know it's sorted out.